# Burninate [quickstart]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[quickstart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quickstart) has 44 questions, 0 followers and no wiki summary.

It appears that the tagged questions are referring to a "quick start" project, code snippet, demo, or configuration provided by various languages and/or tools.

Burninate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with this - that tag is a meta tag at best, and plain terrible at worst. However, before we just flatly remove it from all the questions, I would suggest that we go through them (there's only 44) and see if they need to be closed. A quick survey of the tag revealed several that shouldn't be on the site, I'll try to do a more comprehensive review in the morning.

Comment: I don't have full edit or close vote privileges yet - should I refrain from removing tags and/or issuing close flags?

Comment: @BJMyers, now that you have both, feel free to do so. Remember to remove the tag only from the ontopic posts, and vote to close the bad ones. Lemme know once you're done scanning through, I'll close the posts which you've voted to close, delete the unsalvagable posts and remove the tag from the system.

Comment: @BhargavRao All done.  Thanks!

Comment: @BJMyers, disagreed with a couple of your votes so retagged them. Deleted the remaining. Thanks for the help!